# requested package laravel/spark could not be found in any version

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I am trying to install laravel Spark but getting a lot of errors no matter which method I try.

Upon adding `"laravel/spark": "*@dev"` in the `composer.js` file I am getting this error.

> The requested package laravel/spark could not be found in any version,
>   there may be a typo in the package name.

Any clue what the issue is?

```
"require": {
  "php": ">=5.5.9",
  "laravel/framework": "5.2.",
  "laravel/cashier": "~6.0",
  "laravel/spark": "@dev"
}
```

Added to the `composer.js` file and ran `composer update`. Got the couldn't found error.

Comment: Is `composer.js` typo? You should be editing `composer.json` file for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your `composer.json` file, add the following to the `require` section (note that, compared to what you currently listed, this one has an asterisk `*` before the `@` symbol):

```
"laravel/spark": "*@dev"
```

Then add this in its own section (or update accordingly):

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "./spark",
        "options": {
            "symlink": false
        }
    }
],
```

> The `options` portion is optional and you can leave it out

You can then run your `composer install` command. You can confirm that things are good by running `composer validate`, which will trigger a warning and it's fine to ignore that. You should also check the `composer.lock` file to make sure you have something similar to this in there:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/spark",
    "version": "dev-develop",
    "dist": {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "./spark",
        "reference": "072b0bf217fbbe5018fc062612bb1fb5566d94e1",
        "shasum": null
    },
    "require": {
        "erusev/parsedown": "~1.0",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "~3.0|~4.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "ramsey/uuid": "^3.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "mpociot/vat-calculator": "^1.6",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0"
    },
    "type": "library",
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "4.0-dev"
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Laravel\\Spark\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "license": [
        "MIT"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Taylor Otwell",
            "email": "taylorotwell@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "description": "Laravel Spark provides scaffolding for Laravel SaaS applications.",
    "keywords": [
        "billing",
        "laravel",
        "saas",
        "scaffolding",
        "stripe"
    ],
    "transport-options": {
        "symlink": false
    }
},
```

Also, depending on your version and how you set things up, you'll have to check on the documentation because there's a few different ways to set this up:

https://spark.laravel.com/docs/6.0/installation#installation-via-composer

I'd also add that, you should **never** modify files in the `./spark` directory. All changes are made in either `./resources/assets/js/spark` or `./resources/views/vendor/spark` (and, as always, you can override anything in the `app` directory unless you changed the namespace).

Oh, and these commands may be useful for you (obviously turn these into an actual alias or function that's aliased):

```
alias reset
    rm -rf composer.lock node_modules package-lock.json vendor
    composer install
    npm install
    gulp
    composer validate

alias update
    rm -rf node_modules vendor
    composer install
    npm install
    composer update
    npm update
    reset
```

I would only run these as the branch master though, team members shouldn't have to do dependency updates for Composer and npm.